# webapi odata - long url causes "HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid"

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, self-hosting

We have a project with a selfhosted odata/webapi. When recieving requests with long strings we get the following error:

"HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid"

Is it possible to configure webapi to accept longer parameters?

An example url:

```
GET
/api/bookings/Service.GetSegments(ids='189,196,280,301,316,329,491,511,464,528,530,527,542,372,283,259,231,56,84,98,114,135,175,154,161,85,203,206,217,284,343,344,357,419,425,112,586,432,441,448,455,462,465,358,371,385,392,399,405,413,581,526,538,531,476,490,336,508,525,499,315,260,263,281,224,238,245,246,99,57,58,77,168,180,147,126,133',start='2018-01-20T23:00:00.000Z',end='2018-01-27T23:00:00.000Z')
```

A shorter url like this will work fine:

```
GET
/api/bookings/Service.GetSegments(ids='189,196,280,301,316,329,491',start='2018-01-20T23:00:00.000Z',end='2018-01-27T23:00:00.000Z')
```

This is the method in the controller:

```
 public IHttpActionResult GetSegments(ODataQueryOptions<Segments> odataQueryOption,
        string ids, string start, string end)
    {
       ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace the url segment into a querystring it will work fine.

By default, url segments have maximum length of 260.

Comment: Example on how I ended up using the querystring instead: http://host/service/ProductsByColor(color=@color)?@color='red'